# Cannot log into Ubuntu Server anymore after installing NVIDIA Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, nx

I recently installed a NVIDIA Titan Xp (Galactic Empire Edition) in our Dell PowerEdge R730 Server which uses Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I installed the drivers following the instructions from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Nvidia/nvidia/:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-387 nvidia-settings
```

I also installed CUDA following the instructions from http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html which includes disabling the nouveau driver.

Now we suddenly cannot log into the server anymore per Remote Desktop (NX NoMachine). When I enter my credentials into Ubuntus log in window it takes a few seconds, then the screen goes first black and then brings me back to the log in screen.

This is the output I am getting from ~/.xsession-errors:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (5698) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (5689) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (5542) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (5687) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (5721) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (5722) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (5725) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (5735) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (5702) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (5736) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (5778) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (5669) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 pre-start process (5691) terminated with status 143
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: indicator-sound main process (5732) killed by TERM signal
```

And this I am getting from /var/log/syslog:

```
Dec 18 11:49:03 sauron systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user username.
Dec 18 11:49:05 sauron systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Dec 18 11:49:05 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
Dec 18 11:49:05 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID 124 and group ID 130
Dec 18 11:49:05 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Started (5348)
Dec 18 11:49:05 sauron systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Dec 18 11:49:06 sauron nvidia-persistenced: device 0000:82:00.0 - registered
Dec 18 11:49:06 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Local RPC service initialized
Dec 18 11:49:12 sauron org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[2691]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Dec 18 11:49:12 sauron org.gnome.ScreenSaver[2691]: ** Message: Got disconnected from the session message bus; retrying to reconnect every 10 seconds
Dec 18 11:49:12 sauron dbus[2112]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
Dec 18 11:49:12 sauron systemd[1]: Started Session c4 of user username.
Dec 18 11:49:13 sauron org.a11y.Bus[5552]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Dec 18 11:49:13 sauron org.a11y.Bus[5552]: ** (process:5646): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Dec 18 11:49:13 sauron org.a11y.Bus[5552]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Dec 18 11:49:13 sauron org.a11y.atspi.Registry[5655]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Dec 18 11:49:14 sauron org.ayatana.bamf[5552]: bamfdaemon start/running, process 5669
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron dbus[2112]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service'
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron rtkit-daemon[3071]: Successfully made thread 5763 of process 5763 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron rtkit-daemon[3071]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron org.gnome.ScreenSaver[5552]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron org.gnome.ScreenSaver[5552]: ** (gnome-screensaver:5756): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron dbus[2112]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
Dec 18 11:49:15 sauron gnome-session[5698]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session[5698]: message repeated 3 times: [ Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".]
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session[5698]: gnome-session-is-accelerated: No hardware 3D support.
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session[5698]: Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session[5698]: gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session[5698]: gnome-session-binary[5698]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron gnome-session-binary[5698]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron rtkit-daemon[3071]: Successfully made thread 5816 of process 5816 (n/a) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron rtkit-daemon[3071]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 2 users.
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron pulseaudio[5816]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[5552]: (evolution-source-registry:5765): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[5552]: (evolution-source-registry:5765): GVFS-WARNING **: Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: The connection is closed (g-io-error-quark, 18)
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[5552]: (evolution-source-registry:5765): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5[5552]: (evolution-source-registry:5765): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron lightdm[2614]: /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron lightdm[2614]: message repeated 4 times: [ /etc/modprobe.d is not a file]
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron lightdm[2614]: update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron systemd[1]: Started Session c5 of user lightdm.
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron pulseaudio[5763]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to open mixer for jack detection
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron pulseaudio[5763]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-BVBIhfFbgN: Connection refused
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron pulseaudio[5763]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoServer: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-BVBIhfFbgN: Connection refused
Dec 18 11:49:16 sauron org.a11y.atspi.Registry[5876]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Dec 18 11:49:17 sauron dbus[2112]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.ColorManager' unit='colord.service'
Dec 18 11:49:17 sauron systemd[1]: Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
Dec 18 11:49:17 sauron dbus[2112]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.ColorManager'
Dec 18 11:49:17 sauron systemd[1]: Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Received signal 15
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Socket closed.
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (5348)
Dec 18 11:49:19 sauron systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Dec 18 11:49:30 sauron systemd[1]: Started Session c6 of user lightdm.
Dec 18 11:49:34 sauron systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Dec 18 11:49:34 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
Dec 18 11:49:34 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID 124 and group ID 130
Dec 18 11:49:34 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Started (6161)
Dec 18 11:49:34 sauron systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Dec 18 11:49:35 sauron nvidia-persistenced: device 0000:82:00.0 - registered
Dec 18 11:49:35 sauron nvidia-persistenced: Local RPC service initialized
Dec 18 11:49:37 sauron pulseaudio[5763]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
```

The graphics card is definitively working. I can see it:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2 [102b:0534] (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Embedded Video
        Subsystem: Dell G200eR2 [1028:0600]
--
82:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp] [10de:1b02] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:123f]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Also nvidia-smi displays it and I built an algorithm for CUDA which runs fine and super fast on the card. So why does the remote desktop have problems with it?

Thanks a lot in advance!